# Proof orthogonal functions

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

I have a exercises that I can't do,

a set of functions $$f_{n}(x)$$ is said
orthonormal in an interval $$ a\leqslant x \leqslant b$$, if

$$
 \int_a^b f_{n}(x)\overline{f_{m}(x)}dx= \delta_{nm}
$$

show that $$f_{n}(x)=(1/\sqrt{\pi}) sin(n\pi)$$ is orthogonal over the interval $$ 0\leqslant x \leqslant 2\pi$$

Any ideas, thx

Comment: What is the little * on the function? \

Comment: @DonAntonio it is complex conjugate

Comment: But you're given real valued functions, so that's just the function itself. Then why don't you just carry on with the integrals?

Comment: @DonAntonio because I don't know the value of $$f_{m}$$ function, 
that's my problem

Comment: But you do! it is written in your question: $$f_m(x)=\frac1{\sqrt\pi}\sin nx$$

Comment: you are right, my mistake, I didn't see it, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you need to compute is the integral. Since you know $f_n(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\sin(nx)$, we compute
$$
\int_{0}^{2\pi}f_n(x)\overline{f_m(x)}dx = \int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\sin(nx)\overline{\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\sin(mx)}dx = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sin(nx)\sin(mx)dx.
$$
Notice that $x$ is real then we don't have any complex number here. So the complex conjugate makes no difference. I think you can compute this integral yourself and compare it with $\delta_{nm}$, which equals to 1 if $n=m$ and $0$ if $n\neq m$.